# How to configure SQLServer DataTools project to be able to publish just views or stored procedures without comparing and deploying schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have an existing database which is managed by someone else. I have sufficient rights to create some views or stored procedures. Unfortunatelly the database owner sometimes overwrites my changes and my views disappear. I want to create an SQL Server Database Project which then will allow me to just publish the views. I don't want to keep database schema in my project (it changes, it is huge and I don't care about it). I just want to have my views and sp and be able do deploy only them without comparing the schema. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

Put the views and stored procedures in one project and the tables in another project that you reference from the first project using a "same database" reference.

Just deploy the dacpac with the views/procs in and don't set IncludeCompositeProjects to true.

Make sure you do not enable DropObjectsNotInSource, but it will mean if you rename or delete a proc/view you will need to manually remove it but at least you won't drop the tables etc

Test it properly before you go to production :)

2)

You are fighting the dacpac model of "make this database look like this dacpac" so maybe look at something else, ready roll or flyway or dbup, where you can still source control your code but not have to worry about deploying the schema etc.

If you genuinely only ever need to update views and procs then you could check into source control each object in its own file like:

`create or alter xx`

or if an older version of sql:

`if exists drop`
followed by
`create xx`

the use something like powershell or even dos batch scripts to generate a single deployment script:

`ls -r *.sql | %{ "`r`n---file $($_) ---`r`n";cat $_} > ../deploy.sql`

if all you ever need to update is views and stored procs then you are literally living the dream :)

ed

Comment: The second solution may be better - I don't have, and I don't want to have any project containing the schema. But - can you propose a solution to achieve 2) ?

Comment: I would use Flyway, see Eduardo Piairo's talk: https://www.eduardopiairo.com/tag/winops/ there is a video link as well -  you create a migration for each release which will be alter proc (or create or alter if you are 2016 +). Another option as you have just procs and views, you can get build a deployment script by using "create or alter" (or if an older version if not exists create...) - then you could use powershell to read in each .sql file and output a combined script to be run

Comment: This method assumes that your changes should always "win", which may be what you need. The ideal solution would show you when there's a conflict, in other words someone else has changed a proc that you're also modifying.